# How to fix CORS error when sending a request to express server from react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cors

When I run both the app and the server locally, there is no issue. However, once I deploy the express server, every time I make a request, I get back the following error.

"has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

My server is using cors, and I also tried doing app.options(*, cors()) but that won't work either. I have tried just about every solution online that I could find.

This is what I have in the index.js of the express server.

````
app.options("*", cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));

app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Food Tracker Server");
});```
````

Comment: CORS policy is an important security feature. Disabling it could solve your current problem, but it's not a good solution. Either configure your service to use same origin or learn how to configure CORS.

Answer (score -1):

config your cors like this :

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://example.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}
 
app.get('/', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only example.com.'})
})
 
app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```